# How can I add a column of empty arrays to polars.DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-polars, rust-polars

I am trying to add a column of empty lists to a polars dataframe in python.

My code

```python
import polars as pl
a = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})
a.with_columns([pl.lit([]).alias('b')])
```

throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    a.with_columns([pl.lit([]).alias('b')])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/lazy_functions.py", line 767, in lit
    return pli.wrap_expr(pylit(item, allow_object))
ValueError: could not convert value '[]' as a Literal
```

How can I create this column?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me. I wrote `pl.Series()` with empty lists `[]` as values:

```
import polars as pl
from polars import col

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]}) # .lazy()

df = df.with_columns([
    col('a'),
    pl.Series('empty lists', [[]], dtype=pl.List),
    pl.lit(None).alias('null column'),
])
print(df) # print(df.collect()) (in case of LazyFrame)


┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ a   ┆ empty lists ┆ null column │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ list[f64]   ┆ bool        │
╞═════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ []          ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ []          ┆ null        │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ []          ┆ null        │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but you have to know lengths on the moment of construction, so you cannot use it just in expression, or for a LazyFrame.

Comment: Though you  can do in like this without length! You can edit your answer and I'll mark it as correct answer.
a.with_columns([pl.lit(pl.Series('b', [[]], dtype=pl.List))])

Comment: Yesss) I removed length.